# Retrieve a certain text in a string

Tags: regex, c#-4.0

I'd like a solution to retrieve a text in a string in a c# script
the fomat of the text is 4 digits then _ and 1 to 2 digits

```
test_p_2008_1_Annexe_1_prix
test_p_2008_100_Annexe_1_prix
test_p_2008_1
test_p_2008_100
```

For this 4 examples, i need to get

```
2008_1
2008_100
2008_1
2008_100
```

Maybe use a regex buit i'm not enought good with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're trying to retrieve text which are in 4 digits then _ and 1 to 3 digits format.

```
@"\d{4}_\d{1,3}"
```

Code:

```
String input = @"test_p_2008_1_Annexe_1_prix
test_p_2008_100_Annexe_1_prix
test_p_2008_1
test_p_2008_100";
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"\d{4}_\d{1,3}");
foreach (Match m in rgx.Matches(input))
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[0].Value);
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/nYbtj6)

Comment: or use `@"\d{4}_\d+"` to match all the digits following the `_` symbol.